# Why my other function still running went i break the loop in my main function

Tags: python

The example code that I used
the main idea is when the user enters the wrong input, it will return a menu choice to let the user back to main_menu or continue
but when i want to enter data and choose back to main_menu and try to terminate it, the TenantID function still running

```
def TenantID():              
    while True:       
        error_list = []      
        tenant_id = str(input("1.Enter your Tenant ID: "))
        if ValidateTenantID(tenant_id, error_list):
           print(*error_list)
           if MenuChoice() is True:
              menu()
           else:
              continue
        else:
            break
     return tenant_id


def MenuChoice(): 
    Choice = input("\x1B[1m" + "Press M return to main menu or Any key 
                  to continue: " + '\x1B[0m')
    if Choice in ["M", "m"]:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def ValidateTenantID(tenant_id, error_list):
    returnValue = CheckLength(tenant_id)
    if returnValue is True:
       returnValue = CheckTenantID(tenant_id)
       if returnValue is True:
       returnValue = CheckDataIfExist(tenant_id)
           if returnValue is not True:
           error_list.append(returnValue)
        else:
            error_list.append(returnValue)
     else:
        error_list.append(returnValue)

     return error_list
```

[The problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fl9Sq.png)

Comment: What is `ValidateTenantID()`? What is `menu()`? What calls `TenantID()`?

Comment: You've not shown enough of your code as a [mcve]. Specifically, your image shows you entering 5, printing `Thx`, **then** other output that you're missing.

Comment: @MichaelDelgado There aren't "two things" or threads happening here. OP is given prompts, then is blocking on sub-prompts and validating those.

Comment: that's true. also don't ever use concurrency to manage input. so maybe this isn't a good idea... I got led astray by the "allow loop to continue" without reading carefully enough

Comment: Ok, I see you've added `ValidateTenantID()`. Now apart from indentation problems which I'm putting down to cut and paste, that seems fine. Now what about `menu()`? Is that the problem, you're running recursively?

Comment: thx for your guys feedback，i already found a solution to solve it☺️

Answer (score 1):

If you want to terminate from the menu function, then `return` from it and/or stop the loop that is running it.

For example,

```
running = True

def menu():
    print('options...')
    choice = input('> ')
    if choice == '5':
        global running
        running = False
        return  # completely stop this function from doing other things
    elif choice == '1':
        tid = TenantID()

def TenantID(): 
    valid = False             
    while not valid:       
        error_list = []
        tenant_id = input("1.Enter your Tenant ID: ")
        valid = ValidateTenantID(tenant_id, error_list)
        print(*error_list)
        if MenuChoice():
            break
    if not valid:
        return None
    else:
        return tenant_id

while running:  # can be changed from the menu function via global variable
    menu()
print('bye')
```